# É possível fazer um "texto para voz" com Pyqt?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt-4

Estou aprendendo a mexer com Pyqt. Estou montando uma aplicação simples, onde vai haver uma notificação por voz quando uma nova solicitação estiver disponível.

Eu gostaria que minha aplicação escrita em Pyqt4 pudesse "transformar" um texto em voz.

Consegui fazer isso com HTML5 e Javascript, mas agora eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de fazer algo parecido com Pyqt.

Existe alguma funcionalidade em Pyqt ou que possa ser usada junto com Pyqt para fazer *Text to Speech* (texto para voz)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu acredito que o PyQt4 não tenha suporte para isto, e o pyqt5 talvez só venha suporte em mais no futuro (aparentemente QtSpeech é bem recente), então usar PyQt não é opção, todavia encontrei isto: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyttsx (está um pouco outdate 2012), mas ele é cross-platform e suporte Python2 e isto https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS

### pyttsx

Drivers necessários por ambiente:

- **nsss** - NSSpeechSynthesizer no Mac OS X 10.5 e superior

  Detalhes: https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsspeechsynthesizer
- **sapi5** - SAPI5 no Windows

  Faça o download em https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224
- **espeak** - eSpeak em distros linux

  Instalar no Debian e Ubuntu:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install espeak
  ```

  Para instalar manualmente: http://espeak.sourceforge.net/download.html

Depois pode instalar ele via PIP:

```
pip install pyttsx
```

Veja um exemplo:

```
import pyttsx

engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.say('Hello World!')
engine.runAndWait()
```

Links:

- Repositório: https://github.com/RapidWareTech/pyttsx
- Documentação: http://pyttsx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

> Nos releases do github https://github.com/RapidWareTech/pyttsx/releases e talvez no pip só apareça a versão 1.1, mas na doc já informa sobre a versão 1.2, no caso seria só instalar isto https://github.com/RapidWareTech/pyttsx/tree/master/pyttsx manualmente

A lib por si só não possui os idiomas instalado, quem tem que ter instalado é o driver usado, no caso do eSpeak acho que ele já vem com portugues, para configurar o idioma na lib pode-se usar algo como, o `for` é para obter todas as vozes:

```
engine = pyttsx.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
for voice in voices:
   engine.setProperty('voice', voice.id)  # troca a voz
   engine.say('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.')
engine.runAndWait()
```

Então você vai selecionar a voz que deseja, note que `voices = engine.getProperty('voices')` retorna a classe `class pyttsx.voice.Voice`, que tem as seguintes propriedades:

- `.age` retorna a idade em anos como `integer`
- `.gender` retorna uma `String` que contem o gênero de voz podendo ser `female`, `male` ou `neutral`
- `.id` é o identificador da voz para poder usar no `pyttsx.engine.Engine.setPropertyValue()`
- `.languages` retorna uma `list` de strings que mostra os idiomas suportados pela voz
- `.name` retorna uma `String` contendo um nome "humano" para ajudar a assimilar idioma, genero, etc

No caso você pode usar `voice.languages` para obter o ID do idioma português e assim setar ele.

Se não existir o idioma em portugues na lista é porque o driver não suporta ou não tem instalado o idioma, no caso do linux o e eSpeak já vem com vários idiomas:

- http://espeak.sourceforge.net/languages.html

O Windows também parece já possuir alguns incluindo os em português:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378476(v=office.14).aspx

> O que gostei no espeek é que ele tem suporte para Windows e MacOSX, só não sei se a lib é compatível

---

### gTTS

O gTTS (Google Text to Speech) é uma interface que transforma texto em audio e salva em um .mp3

Para instalar rode o PIP:

```
pip install gTTS
```

Uso:

```
from gtts import gTTS

tts = gTTS(text='Hello', lang='en')

tts.save("hello.mp3") #Salva o arquivo
```

Em português:

```
from gtts import gTTS

tts = gTTS(text='Olá', lang='pt-br')

tts.save("ola.mp3") #Salva o arquivo
```

Idiomas suportados: https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS#lang_list