# Gerenciador de comandos de voz Siri

Tags: python, api, osx, lib

Sei que meu macbook tem o tts (text to speech) ao digitar comand say. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma API ou alguma biblioteca que trabalhe com isso em python. Ou teria que fazer manualmente?

Alguem recomenda algo? Obrigado.

Comment: Veja se isto resolve https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/161812/3635

Comment: Possível duplicata de [É possível fazer um "texto para voz" com Pyqt?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/161804/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-fazer-um-texto-para-voz-com-pyqt)

Comment: Nao e uma duplicata. Nesse post, ele pergunta se e possivel fazer um tts. Eu sei que e possivel e fiz em javascript. Quero saber se existe algum gerenciador que trabalhe com o say do OSX.

Comment: Amigo, eu segui o que esta no corpo da sua pergunta e conforme as tags, a resposta apresenta a `lib` e os drivers necessários. Agora se você esta pedindo por um software especifico que nada tem haver com programação, então a pergunta é off-topic, conforme o proprio Help indica: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Espero realmente que entenda.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não esta pedindo um software e sim um repositório ou plugin.

Comment: @GuilhermeIazzetta tem certeza? Então porque a resposta aceita foi justamente um software pronto e não um exemplo de código de uma lib? Poderia explicar? Talvez ajude outros usuários e poderemos reabrir a pergunta ;)

Comment: Esta pergunta esta sendo debatida no Meta: [Pergunta sobre “OS X Speech Synthesis Manager” seria on-topic?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5977/3635)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OS X Speech Synthesis Manager e um gerenciador de Speech do OSx. Da uma olhada nisso, acredito ser o que voce procura: https://ankiatts.appspot.com/services/say

Comment: Amigo somos uma comunidade de programação, se você notar que a pergunta é off-topic, conforme indica o link do **proprio** site https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, então prefira comentar apenas.  O melhor nestes casos é só comentar e sinalizar a pergunta. ;)

Comment: Não considero off topic nem repetido.

Comment: @CarlosZillner sério? Apontar apenas um link para algo que parece uma aplicação pronta, independente da linguagem que for escrita não me parece o escopo do site *Stack Overflow em Português*, mas se você puder explicar o ponto com mais algum detalhe ficarei feliz em reabrir a questão.

Comment: Ele pergunta sobre libs de TTS, talvez a pergunta precise de edição e não criminalização...rs mas é totalmente relevante. Poderia ser um topico para listarmos engines e libs de TTS. Entendo que o trabalho de moderação deve ser para ajudar a pessoa que perguntou a chegar num formato legal para a comunidade. O título da pergunta ta bem ruim, mas a descrição deixa claro o que ele quer. Deveria ser reformulada.

Comment: @CarlosZillner creio que você não esteja entendendo o foco do site e muito menos o sistema de organização, isso não é opinião minha, é o escopo do site que esta bem definido https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, fechar algo não é "criminalizar" é apenas para prevenir respostas fora do escopo, se necessário a pergunta pode ser reaberta a qualquer momento. A resposta não aponta LIB alguma, aponta um software pronto, independente da linguagem que foi escrita, não é uma pergunta sobre "programação" ou ferramenta para programação, a resposta foi um software pronto e só. ;)

Comment: @CarlosZillner esta pergunta e resposta estão sendo debatidas no Meta do site: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5977/3635 (área para debates e resolver impasses como este), recomendo que participe para promover tua opinião sobre o assunto.